# inserting data in mysql by text file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following data in the text file

```
   Lat      Lon      Cls
   -89.75  -179.75   EF
   -89.75  -179.25   EF
   -89.75  -178.75   EF
   -89.75  -178.25   EF
   -89.75  -177.75   EF
   -89.75  -177.25   EF
   -89.75  -176.75   EF
```

and i have to insert in in the mysql database in the following table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jos_lat_log` (
`Lat` text NOT NULL,
`Lon` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`climatefamily` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

i am using the following query to insert

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Koeppen-Geiger-ASCII.txt' 
INTO TABLE `jos_lat_log` FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

the above query is working but it is inserting data in only one column but i have to insert it in all three columes

Comment: just for testing, try to remove the first row: [Lat Lon Cls] from the text file and try to import again. does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

if your fields are seperated by a space,

```
TERMINATED BY ' '
```

with a space between quotes

Answer (score 0):

Your fields in the file are terminated by a space ' ', but you have listed '' in your query. Just change `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''` to `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' '`